# Does base64 encoding preserve alphabetical ordering?

Tags: sorting, encoding, base64

Let's say I have a list of 100 words, sorted in alphabetical order.
If I base64 encode these words, and then order the resulting list again, will the order of the elements be the same?

If not, is there any other encoding algorithm that will provide this behaviour for me?

Comment: This sounds very easily test-able with very minimal effort. Check out https://www.base64encode.org/. My guess is that yes the order is preserved between encoding and decoding with base64.

Comment: I can run a small test like that and see if the sorting is maintained for that set, but it's hard to actually prove that will work for all sets of words. I'm afraid there will be some rare cases where the ordering is not preserved.

Comment: I honestly do not understand the exact situation which you are afraid of. Can you provide a sample of what you fear will happen?

Comment: Sure, we have a large set of data which will be exposed by an API. We want to return the data set in pages, where each page contains a continuation token that points to the next page. We also want the data set to be returned in alphabetical order of a certain field in the data. So the idea was to concatenate this field with its record ID (for uniqueness) and then save that value as an extra column in the database. Then we can use that column as the continuation token and easily select the next top X records.

Comment: If the alphabetical order is not preserved by base64 encoding, that could result in missing records from the result set.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, base64 does not preserve sort order of the unencoded strings.

This is explained in RFC 4648, [which also defines an encoding called base32hex](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-10), which specifically does guarantee that it maintains sort order.

If you want to stick with an official standard, base32hex is the best option I'm aware of.

If the space-efficiency of your encoding is important, though, dropping from base64 down to base32 is a bit of a bummer. If that's the case, you could always create your own encoding (it isn't all that hard) or adopt someone else's (JavaScript example: https://github.com/dominictarr/d64).

Comment: [uuencode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) is an existing standard that preserves sort order since it just uses the 64 sequential characters from <space> to _ to encode the data.

Comment: Similarly, if space-efficiency doesn't matter too much, hexadecimal (base 16) is still an option and it's a simpler encode/decode to/from binary.